# Как сделать рефакторинг одной относительной гипер ссылки в HTML странице ручным способом так, чтобы изменения произошли во всех местах

Tags: html, css, ide

Я пользовался IDE PHPStorm при работе с HTML и CSS.  При помощи этой умнейшей IDE я одним нажатием кнопки решал вопрос переименования CSS классов, адресов гипер ссылок, названий HTML страниц и т.п. В PHPStorm есть опция refactor, когда применяешь эту функцию, то наименование меняется во всех местах где оно существует. Например, у меня меняется название какого-то CSS класса во всех местах на всех HTML страницах, где к этому классу привязаны HTML элементы, относительные гипер ссылки на другие страницы этого же веб сайта существуют в нескольких местах, они также меняются все пакетным способом автоматически. И вот теперь у меня беда!  Триальный период IDE закончился, я думал, что подобная функция refactor есть и в других IDE, но я не могу найти пока ни в одной бесплатной среде разработки эту функцию. Страниц слишком много и переименовывать на каждой странице просто бессмысленно, на это уйдет месяц. Какие существуют способы выполнять это действие? Я ищу уже 4 -ый день, читаю и смотрю видео, думал найду какие-то скрипты или инструкции. И не могу найти, я даже не знаю какую тему читать и изучать, чтобы найти способы. Подозреваю, что нужно искать по темам - Простанство имен, регулярные выражения и т.п., но эти темы также очень большие, там великое множество информации, пока не могу найти то, что мне нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста способы, моя работа встала, я только трачу время на поиски, и не могу дальше заниматься веб-сайтом.

Comment: А может психануть и купить лицензию? Тем более, что при оплате за год, вы получаете вечную лицензию, правда без обновлений в дальнейшем, если продлевать не будете.

Comment: Я куплю лицензию, когда начну этим зарабатывать. Пока только учусь. Смысл покупать, если это пока обучение. А как же работают люди в других IDE? Есть наверняка способы сделать это вручную при помощи скриптов и написания программ, но я не могу их пока найти.

Comment: либо купить лицензию и пользоваться продуктом, который решает Вашу задачу в понятный Вам способ. Либо написать свою тулу. А можно заказать работу на стороне. В любом случае придется заплатить, деньгами, временем или всем вместе.

Comment: Написать свою тулу? А как это по английски будет написано? И какую тему нужно изучать, чтобы написать эту тулу? И на каком языке ее писать? То, что писать какую то программу нужно, я это уже понял. Только какую именно, вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: Вам явно нужен будет парсер, который поможет построить ast дерево кода. А когда оно есть, то уже легко понять, что представляет собой каждое слово. Но это очень глобальненькая задача. На 3-4 года минимум. Начать можно с книги "дракона" по компиляторам. Но это очень огромная задача.

Comment: ребята, вы серьезно? это же просто в VSCode

Comment: Ой... 3-4 года? Тогда не имеет смысла этим заниматься, если это занимает столько времени. Человек посоветовал только что в Visual Studio Code выделить нужное и нажать F2. Сейчас буду пробовать. Но спасибо за ваш ответ. Хотя бы изучу новую для себя тему.

Comment: да, это не легкая задача. Но часто ее решают просто "найти-заменить".

Comment: Спасибо. Буду изучать

Comment: @KoVadim а разве в связке `HTML-CSS` случай описанный ТС не является "найти-заменить" функционалом?

Comment: найти-заменить может сделать чуточку больше или меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Могу только сказать, как данную штуку провернуть в `Visual Studio Code`.

Все что нужно сделать здесь так это выделить переменную, метод или класс и нажать <kbd>F2</kbd>. Каждый экземпляр будет переименован во всем проекте.

Чтобы данную фичу применить только к текущему документу нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Ух ты! Неужели все так просто? Сейчас непременно попробую!!!

Comment: Но теперь в Visual Studio Code нужно создать проект и корневой каталог привязать к проекту, чтобы  этот каталог воспринимался как корневой каталог проекта. А как же мне это сделать в Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Создать Workspace=) Как с любым новым ПО, надо будет покумекать и поучиться

Comment: Да понял. В PHPStorm тоже есть workspace, там я также создавал проект из существующей директории, он долго индексирует и потом появляется папка с названием .idea - в этой папке я так понимаю все и хранится по проекту. Буду пробовать. Спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyBabann на здоровье. Обратите внимание, что здесь не  принято говорить "спасибо" ни в комментариях ни как либо еще. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Друзья у меня хорошая новость! Я применил функцию refactor в IDE Netbeans. Оказывается чтобы среда разработки воспринимала исходный код проекта как код именно этого проекта, а не просто непойми что, нужно было поместить исходный код в папку проекта public_html, именно которая создается автоматически при создании проекта самой IDE. Папка public_html c исходным кодом не должна находиться за пределами проекта. И IDE Netbeans оказывается умеет выполнять функцию refactor так же, как это умеет делать PhpStorm. Я очень рад!!! Конечно есть ряд вещей, которые на данный момент Netbeans не делает, что умеет делать PhpStorm, но это уже не смертельно, там можно выкрутиться. Так что я решил свою проблему. А советы по поводу workspace в IDE Visual Studio Code навели меня на мысль о том, чтобы я поместил исходный код веб-сайта в папку public_html, именно в ту папку, которая находится в папке проекта, а не за его пределами. 4 дня я потратил в поисках и попытках, чтобы решить этот вопрос. И решил.